# Why is there no "Restart" option in the power button shut down dialogue?

Tags: release-odin

Elementary OS 5 would give you the full shutdown dialogue box when you press the power button after enabling it in the settings. This functioned identically as pressing "Shut down" under the power option in the top panel. Now on eOS 6 when you press the power button it pops up with an identical dialogue box but without the restart option: you can only Shut Down or Cancel. Is there a way to get this back or are you just stuck using the terminal or the power dialogue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been addressed already - I have an option to restart when I left click the power icon and select Shut down... as well as when I middle click the power icon.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the middle click option. I just find it odd that they would go through the effort of giving you a different menu when you press the power button than when click through the shut down menus.